# Converting arraylist into List in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have an arraylist named "ObjectArray" , to do some perfomance improvement and get rid of casting issues , I thought of to use Generic List, how can I convert following arralist to List? I know `ToList()` will do but how to do in this scenario

```
public class ObjectArray : ArrayList
  {}



 ObjectArray col = ObjectArray.Deserialize(xml, Type.type);


Testobject tmo;

tmo= (Testobject)col[i];
```

Comment: Where is the casting you want to get rid of? The name of your class is `ObjectArray`. So it seems that you need to change the base class from `ArrayList` to `List<object>`, which seems to have no benefit.

Comment: Where do you need your List<T> and why does a .ToList() not work in that context? Do you get errors?

Comment: Why you're using _ArrayList_ if you want to use _List<T>_?

Comment: @MD.Unicorn i am getting casting issue on line dmo = (DataModelObject)col[i]; in a few occasions

Comment: Do you always have only `DataModelObject`s in the collection? Or it may also contain object of another type?

Answer (score 2):

You should not be inheritting from `List<T>`, but `Collection<T>` instead. Per MSDN docs:

> System.Collections.Generic.List is a generic collection designed for
>   performance not inheritance and, therefore, does not contain any
>   virtual members.
>
> The Collection class can be used immediately by creating an instance
>   of one of its constructed types; all you have to do is specify the
>   type of object to be contained in the collection. In addition, you can
>   derive your own collection type from any constructed type, or derive a
>   generic collection type from the Collection class itself.

Inherit from `Collection` as follows. Inside your class, you can then override (if needed) the basic collection behavior and/or add your own implementation.

```
public class ObjectArray : Collection<T>
```

See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Stop for a second; you are trying to have one class do two things. You are also moving compile-time problems to run-time. I would suggest you deserialize strong types and store them in strongly typed lists rather than everything in one.

i.e.

```
 ViewModel[] viewModels= Serializer.DeserialiseViewModels(fromSomething);
 DataModel[] dataModels= Serializer.DeserialiseDataModels(fromSomething);
```

In anycase, you are concerned with deserializing types and adding them to a list. So don't bother with a new collection class because you don't need to reinvent the wheel here.

SO lets assume you've deserialised an array of objects i.e.

```
object[] loaded = ObjectArraySerializer.Deserialise(fromSomething);
```

Now you want to get all the items of type T1 and T2

```
List<T1> itemsT1 = loaded.OfType<T1>().ToList()
List<T2> itemsT2 = loaded.OfType<T2>().ToList()
```

Now assuming

```
where T1: TBase, where T2: TBase
```

you can do

```
List<TBase> TBaseItems = itemsT1.Cast<TBase>().Concat(itemsT2.Cast<TBase>()).ToList();
```

or you could do that straight off the bat;

```
List<TBase> tbaseItems= loaded.OfType<TBase>().ToList();
```

Comment: can you modify answer based on my question?

Comment: so if i did this code List<DataModelObject> itemsT1 = col.OfType<DataModelObject>().ToList(); after exisitng line ObjectArray col = ObjectArray.Deserialize(xml, a.GetType(myType, true));  will that work?

Comment: Well if you know you'll be deserialising a specific type; what about: ObjectArray.Deserialize(xml, typeof(T)).Cast<T>().ToList(); ? But yes, that code above should work to grab all the datamodels from the already deserialised array

Comment: That will never work, since all types i am getting from different assembly on runtime

Comment: Don't they implement a common interface?